# Getting acroForms from PDDocument

Tags: pdfbox

As a result of migrating pdfbox from version 1.8.6 to 2.0.12 the following code

```
    document = PDDocument.load(pdfDocumentAsInputStream);
    final COSDictionary trailer = document.getDocument().getTrailer();
    final COSDictionary root = (COSDictionary) trailer.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ROOT);
    final COSDictionary acroForm = (COSDictionary) root.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ACRO_FORM);
    final COSArray fields = (COSArray) acroForm.getDictionaryObject(COSName.FIELDS);
```

is returning null at

```
final COSDictionary acroForm = (COSDictionary) root.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ACRO_FORM);
```

InputStream is valid, first lines are working.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. `root.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ACRO_FORM)` is what PDFBox' `PDDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm()` does, too, and this usually works.

Comment: First part you mean to make the pdf available here? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Right. Apparently the code does not find the **AcroForm** object there, so the PDF needs to be analyzed.

Comment: SOLVED: It was a misunderstanding of what acroForm is. Of course it returns null, if there is (in my case) no signature what means there is no acroForm. If I now understand it right.

Comment: Great! Please make that an actual answer and accept it or delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved.

If someone is actually have similar issuses:

AcroForm exists only if there are interactive forms in the pdf.

In my case non-signed PDFs have no AcroForms so the method returns correctly
 `null`
and throws a 
`NullPointerException` at 
`final COSArray fields = (COSArray) acroForm.getDictionaryObject(COSName.FIELDS);`.